# How to change error reporting level in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, error-reporting

How can i change the PHP error_reporting in L4?

I found this http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=6072, but it's about L3 and i can't figure out how to achieve that same goal, that is **prevent the application from throwing exception on php E_NOTICE**.

Answer (score 10):

User "your common sense" (awesome name btw) is right about fixing the error.
Welcome in 2013, the 'undefined index error' is a thing from the past these days.

Except if you are working with legacy code which can't be altered that simple...
So here we go:

In the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php` the `error_reporting()` is set to `-1`, aka: "report ALL the errors".
Try to change the level of error_reporting, link to manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Edit your `global.php` in the /app directory, and add at the bottom: `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);`

Undefined index errors wont show anymore. Feel free to adjust the level to your needs.

[edit]
Ow by the way: in app/config/app.php (or app/config/-environment-/app.php you can alter the debug to false. In this way the user of your app wont getting any technical error-messages.

Comment: Thank you, that's what i've done this morning, but in app.php rather than global.php. What i'm after is the Laravel recommended way of doing this, that is a real-world need and the goal of php native error_reporting() itself, more than theoretical points i never asked help about

Comment: @brazorf I'm not sure what you ask. Currently (as far as I known) there is no method in laravel to control the level of error_reporting.

Comment: Hey Rob, i just want to prevent my application from throwing exception on php E_NOTICE.

Comment: so add `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` in app.php or global.php.

Answer (score 0):

Just set error reporting 0 in app\start\global.php in the top of the page.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Answer (score -2):

Citing from the forum you linked to:

> now you should know as a programmer **you need to fix the error and not hide it.**

Comment: Thank you for this piece of wisdom. I know how to handle errors, and as a programmer i'm aware of what should break my app and what should not.

Comment: from the php docs: Enabling E_NOTICE during development has some benefits. For debugging purposes: NOTICE messages will warn you about possible bugs in your code. For example, use of unassigned values is warned. It is extremely useful to find typos and to save time for debugging. NOTICE messages will warn you about bad style. For example, $arr[item] is better to be written as $arr['item'] since PHP tries to treat "item" as constant. If it is not a constant, PHP assumes it is a string index for the array.

Comment: You win the award for most useless rely on StackOverflow. Congratulations.